# Strange unicode crash

Tags: ruby, debugging, unicode, sms

One of my Rails apps received four text messages from an ATT number, and each message was prefaced with this (sequentially):

```
\u0005\u0000\u0003?\u0004\u0001 Message 1...

\u0005\u0000\u0003?\u0004\u0002 Message 2...

\u0005\u0000\u0003?\u0004\u0003 Message 3...

\u0005\u0000\u0003?\u0004\u0004 Message 4...
```

The app crashed each time with the error "string contains null byte".

They don't seem to decode as any unicode that I recognize.  Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Well, it's certainly valid UTF-8 (and ASCII—all of the bytes are in the 0+0000 to 0+007F range). However, I doubt this is intended to be read as text. The fact that the sixth byte starts at 0+0001 and is strictly ascending suggests that it indicates order. However, without knowing where these values are coming from it's impossible to know more. You should probably consult the documentation for whatever API you're using to receive SMSes, or at the very least add more details to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick googling (for "SMS header," perhaps a lucky guess) reveals that this is an SMS User Data Header (UDH); specifically one that describes a "Concatenated SMS" (CSMS), i.e. a long message that's been split into multiple messages. Wikipedia has a good overview: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS The octets described there match exactly what you're seeing:

1. `05`: Length of the User Data Header, in this case 5.
2. `00`: Information Element Identifier; `00` is the identifier for Concatenated SMS.
3. `03`: Length of the header excluding the first two fields (I think this is so multiple headers can be used one after the other, in which case the first octet would be the total length of all headers).
4. `3F`: The CSMS identifier, i.e. an ID shared by all of the message parts. (Ruby displays this as `?` because 0+003F happens to be UTF-8 code point for the question mark.)
5. `04`: The total number of parts.
6. `00-FF`: This part's number in the sequence.

I recommend reading the Wikipedia article; it's pretty easy to grok, and I'm sure I've oversimplified some things.

Making use of this header to join CSMS parts back together would be a fun problem. I'm surprised that whatever API you're using doesn't do that for you, though.

Comment: Brilliant!  I noticed the ascending octet, never occurred to me that it would be a header.  Our sms provider just sends us an http post with each message.